# iterm 2 issuing commands in multiple panes with parameters

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I am using iterm for deployment into multiple servers and use the feature to run the common command to issue to all the panels. This is a good feature. However, there are times when I need to run the parametrized commands.i.e, hostname will be different and I would parametrize the hostname. Is this possible to issue parametrized command in iterm2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Broadcast to multiple shells using env. variables assigned to different values in each shell:

shell #1:

```
>echo $RANDOM
11798
```

and shell #2 shows:

```
>echo $RANDOM
21342
```

So assign your hostname to a local env. variable (i.e. DEPLOYMENTHOSTNAME=DifferentHost) in each shell before enabling broadcasting and then you can enable broadcasting:

```
>cd ~/releasebuild
>scp newlibrary.so pradeep@$DEPLOYMENTHOSTNAME:/remote/deploy/directory
```

Comment: And once after creating the panes and setting the environment variables, can we save the settings with some name so that next time I can open all the panes with the configurations already defined? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: iTerm2 2.9.x (Beta) can restore sessions that were closed, but I do not think it can re-assign env. variables. I would create a different Profile for each of your different remote hosts and either assign each one a different script to execute on creation or if you just have one env var to assign, set it in the Profile's Command section. Manually open each profile, drag the windows to where you need each one, Save the 'Window Arrangement' and you can reopen that arrangement later, each shell will get the env. var assigned and the windows will be restored their original placement.